# How can I read an array of data from a text file in my code in C programming?

Tags: c, arrays, text

I have a code that reads a text file which has a bunch of numbers. I use the code below to access it but this only grabs the first line.

I have 99 other lines of data I want to access. How do I make it read the other 99 lines of data ?

```
fscanf(fp1,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&a,&b,&c,&d);
```

Comment: have you ever tried getting data line by line from the file and parsing every line data with fscanf ?

Comment: As I have mentioned there are 99 more rows of data to go through. I do not know how to do what you have mentioned efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As elia mentions in the comments, the best strategy is to read the whole line
and then parse it with `sscanf`.

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp1))
{
    if(sscanf(buffer,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&a,&b,&c,&d) != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line format, ignoring\n");
        continue;
    }

    printf("a: %lf, b: %lf, c: %ld, d: %lf\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

Another option is to keep reading until `\n`:

```
while(1)
{
    if(fscanf(fp1,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&a,&b,&c,&d) != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid line format, ignoring\n");
        if(clear_line(fp1) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read from fp1 anymore\n");
            break;
        }
        continue;
    }

    printf("a: %lf, b: %lf, c: %ld, d: %lf\n", a, b, c, d);

    if(clear_line(fp1) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read from fp1 anymore\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

and `clear_line` looks like this:

```
int clear_line(FILE *fp)
{
    if(fp == NULL)
        return 0;

    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    return c != EOF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
fscanf(fp1,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf",&a,&b,&c,&d);
```

hints that there are only 4 numbers per line in the input file.

The posted code suggests:

```
float a;
float b;
float c;
float d;
```

and that the numbers on the line are separated by commas

Suggest:

```
#define MAX_LINES 100

float a[ MAX_LINES ];
float b[ NAX_LINES ];
float c[ MAX_LINES ];
float d[ MAX_LINES ];

size_t i = 0;
while( i<MAX_LINES && 4 == fscanf( fp1, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &a[i], &b[i], &c[i], &d[i] )
{ 
    // perhaps do something with the most recent line of data
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided reads data from the file using the `fscanf` function, but as you mentioned, it only reads the first line of data. To read the other 99 lines of data from the file, you need to use a loop to repeatedly call `fscanf` until you reach the end of the file or read all the lines you want. You can use a `while` loop for this purpose. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp1;
    double a, b, c, d;
    
    // Open the file for reading
    fp1 = fopen("your_file.txt", "r");
    
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fscanf(fp1, "%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4) {
        // Process the data (a, b, c, d) from each line here
        // You can perform any necessary operations on the data
        
        // If you want to print the values as an example
        printf("%lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", a, b, c, d);
    }
    
    // Close the file when done
    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the `while` loop reads lines from the file one by one using `fscanf` until it reaches the end of the file. The loop will continue as long as `fscanf` successfully reads four values (assuming that each line in your file contains four numbers separated by commas). You can adjust the number of values based on your file's format.

Within the loop, you can process the values `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` as needed. This code will process all the lines in the file, not just the first one.